# Regression line in legend should be thinner

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, line, legend

I am ploting points with regression line.  Size of points is in a variable.
Regression line in legend is plotted with different width than in my graph.

```
df = data.frame( x=1:20, y=(1:20)^ 2 , t=20:1 )
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,size=t)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='loess')
```

I get this graph.  Look legend is not real.
[image: graphic with legend error]

Regression line in legend should be thinner.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe move size into geom_point() instead of in global aes in ggplot()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple!  Just add a size parameter.  You can choose any number you like, I think .5 is a nice crisp line

```
library( ggplot2 )
df = data.frame( x=1:20, y=(1:20)^ 2 , t=20:1 )
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,size=t)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='loess', size=.5)
```

[image]